ALSA problem using speech recognition on Debix model A
Card : Debix Model A
OS : Ubuntu 22.04
Hello I'm trying to work on a speech recognition script using Edgeimpulse on an Debix model A card running a Ubuntu 22.04 OS. When I try to run it I get theses errors :
ALSA lib pcm_dshare.c:701:(snd_pcm_dshare_open) The dshare plugin support only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1005:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin support only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dsoop.c:601:(snd_pcm_dsoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:297:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp

the last error is :
After looking at all the topics on many different forum, the one that seems to work was to include sounddevice. But I still get the Segmentation fault (core dumped) at the end.
I'm using an electret microphone connected trought the jack connector of the board. I believe the sound card is the es8316
I also tried to install OSS4 and to bypass ALSA but I get the same errors message again and again.
Have any of you tried this ?
